# YoloV4 Darknet issue

Tags: object-detection, darknet, yolov4

I am trying to run  ./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg
on my Mac m1 terminal after installation of darknet
but it is showing me this -
'/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib' (no such file),

Comment: plz help me in this

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. this question needs debugging details.

Comment: How did you install darknet?